# Adding a new computer to domain script (Error)

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am having a problem executing this script leading to an error which I don't understand, the script worked perfectly, always.

If anyone has an idea what may be the cause of this error it would be really helpful.

This is the script:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $domain = "lon.lab"
)
$name = Read-Host "Enter your computer name"
$username = "$domain\administrator"
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Password for $username" -AsSecureString
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)

Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $cred -NewName $name
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
Add-Computer : Computer 'WIN-5V8QHNCLO9U' failed to join domain 'lon.lab' from
its current workgroup 'WORKGROUP' with following error message: Cannot complete
this function.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NewPcToDomain.ps1:10 char:1
+ Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $cred
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (WIN-5V8QHNCLO9U:String) [Add-Computer], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailToJoinDomainFromWorkgroup,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddComputerCommand
```

**Edit:** I added the `-Verbose` Parameter like so:

```
Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $cred -NewName $name -Verbose
```

I just don't get how or why this worked.

Comment: I don't see why the code should not work. Maybe some temporary hiccup? Can you reproduce the issue? Do you see anything on the domain controller (in the eventlog)?

Comment: Do you have any stale SRV records in DNS? Sounds like a classic case of DNS resolving to a non-DC (or a demoted DC)

Comment: Not quite sure i checked DNS records, 2 possible causes are that i had a trust between two completely different forests Domain.A and Domain.B, I deleted Domain.B (Forest) , but the DNS records for Domain.B are still on the Domain.A (Forest) , This is one .

The next is that i had another DC with the same name as the DC i am adding to the domain which is "Lon-dc2", but i made sure there were no (A) records for "Lon-dc2" , I'm not sure if this could make some sort of conflict .